# Chef cannot upload cookbook to automate server

Tags: chef-infra, automated-deploy

I m trying to upload a test cookbook from my windows client to automate server.
The chef server received the cookbook , I can see it in the management console , the command return Uploaded 1 cookbook but doesn t work on automate server .

here is the error from nginx:
    "POST /data-collector/v0/ HTTP/1.1" 401 
seems to be auth issues but cannot understand why

here are my configuration files:

chef server

```
data_collector["root_url"] = 'https://autome_fqdn/data-collector/v0/'
data_collector["token"] = 
"93a49a4f2482c64126f7b6015e6b0f30284287ee4054ff8807fb63d9cbd1c506"
```

automate server

```
delivery_fqdn "full_fqdn"
delivery['chef_username'] = "delivery"
delivery['chef_private_key'] = "/etc/delivery/delivery.pem"
delivery['chef_server'] = 'https://chef_server/organizations/org'
insights['enable'] = true
```

Comment: That error is unrelated, what is the full client side error using the debug log level?

Comment: no error fom the client side everyting is ok

Comment: So what makes you think something is wrong?

Comment: cannot find the cookbook on the automate UI, just in the chef server